# Toolbar with class "toolbar-bottom" creates incorrect padding for page content

Tags: material-design, html-framework-7

Using Framework7, I created a toolbar. It worked great for the iOS theme. However, when I tested it on the material theme, it was on the top. I found some Framework7 documentation that pointed me to the "toolbar-bottom" class. However, the page-content acted as if the toolbar was still on the top, and the padding-top property was incorrect. I would not like to hard code overrides on the Framework7 css.

Here is my structure:

```
<div class="page navbar-fixed toolbar-fixed">
  <div class="navbar">...</div>
  <div class="page-content">...</div>
  <div class="toolbar toolbar-bottom">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR read the docs you dumb OP

See [this documentation page](https://framework7.io/docs/app-layout.html). In order for the CSS to work correctly, the toolbar must be before the page-content. Your format should look like this:

```
<div class="page navbar-fixed toolbar-fixed">
  <div class="navbar">...</div>
  <div class="toolbar toolbar-bottom">...</div>
  <div class="page-content">...</div>
</div>
```